# Sum of the Difference between the first letter and the last letter, second letter and the penultimate letter, and so on till the center of the word

Tags: java, string

If the given string is “WORLD WIDE WEB”
In each word, find the Sum of the Difference between the first letter and the last letter, second letter and the penultimate letter, and so on till the center of the word.

WORLD = [W-D]+[O-L]+[R] = [23-4]+[15-12]+[18] = [19]+[3]+[18] = [40]

WIDE = [W-E]+[I-D] = [23-5]+[9-4] = [18]+[5] = [23]

WEB = [W-B]+[E] = [23-2]+[5] = [21]+[5] = [26]

Concatenate the sums of each word to form the result

[40] [23] [26]

[402326]

```
class Strcode{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int xd[]=new int[100];
        int n[]=new int[100];
        int position=0;
        String input = "hello".toLowerCase(); //note the to lower case in order to treat a and A the same way
        for( int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
            position = input.charAt(i) - 'a' + 1;
            System.out.println(position);
            for( int k=0,j=position.length()-1;k<j;k++,j--){
                xd[k]=Math.abs(xd[k]-xd[j]);
                System.out.println(xd[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the above code i am able to get numerical value of letters, but failed to do next step of subtraction.

Comment: what do you mean, you fail to subtract? that's the easy part

Comment: In my opinion, for this snippet a recursive function would be very useful...

Comment: You should think about giving your variables meaningful names. Using just i, k, xs making it hard for others to understand.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `position.length()-1` when `position` is `int`? Consider creating some pseudocode first and then try to convert it into real one. Also if you are allowed to, try creating some helper methods like `int positionInAlphabet(char ch)` so you could write something like `positionInAlphabet('W')-positionInAlphabet('B')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is one of the basic problems for beginners. Let me crack it down for you. You need to perform following steps :

1. Extract each word from your given string. ( Do it on your own! )
2. Calculate sum for each word. ( Find below code! )
3. Concatenate these sums. ( Easy! )

   ```
   public class sample{

   public static void main(String args[]){

       // Do your part of code here

       String sampleWord = "hello";
       int individualWordSum = countSum(sampleWord);

   }

   public static int countSum(String word){

     String input = word.toLowerCase();
     int sum = 0;

     for( int i = 0; i < input.length()/2; i++) {
         int s = (input.charAt(i) - 'a') - (input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - i) - 'a');
         sum += Math.abs(s);
     }

     if(input.length()%2!=0){
       sum += input.charAt(input.length()/2) - 'a' + 1;
     }

     System.out.println("sum for " + input + " is " + sum);

     return sum;
    }
   }
   ```

Here is the complete code you need, but first try on your own.

```
public class sample{
public static void main(String args[]){

    String sentence = "WORLD WIDE WEB";
    String words[] = sentence.split(" ");
    String result = "";

    for(String word : words){
      result += String.valueOf(countSum(word));
    }

    System.out.println("Sum for " + sentence + " is " + result);

}

public static int countSum(String word){

  String input = word.toLowerCase();
  int sum = 0;

  for( int i = 0; i < input.length()/2; i++) {
      int s = (input.charAt(i) - 'a') - (input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - i) - 'a');
      sum += Math.abs(s);
  }

  if(input.length()%2!=0){
    sum += input.charAt(input.length()/2) - 'a' + 1;
  }

  return sum;

}
}
```

Comment: By proving full input as -> (hello world), it's return the output as -->
sum for hello is 26
sum for world is 40
but the expected output is to concatenate them and output as 2640.

Comment: That is the point 1 and 3, which you need to implement. Give it a try. If still you face problem i will guide you on that as well.

Comment: Yes, i done that. I was much near to do it by myself, thanks a lot for your support. @jack jay

Answer (score 0):

You can make it quite simpler if instead of implementing the described logic, you analyze it and get a simpler solution.

Instead of summing up the difference between the first letter and the last letter and so on, you can sum the first half of the word (including the middle letter if the word is of odd length) and subtract the second half.

```
String sentance = "WORLD";
int middle = Math.ceil(sentance.length() / 2);
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sentance.length(); i++)
{
    if (i <= middle)
    {
        sum += sentance[i] - 'A' + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        sum -= sentance[i] - 'A' + 1;
    }
}

System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

You'll get:

> Sum: 40